# Find pdf of first order statistic for uniform distribution

Tags: statistics

> Given ${X_1,X_2,..X_n}$ be identical independently distributed with U(0,1) then is the pdf of $Y=X_{(1)}$ is $3y*(y-1)^3$ on $[0,1]$.

I know that pdf($X_{(1)}$)=$pdf(x)*(1-F(x))^{(n-1)}$ is this the correct approach

Comment: The wiki page is good enough for answering this question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Cumulative_distribution_function_of_order_statistics. It will be a $\mathsf{Beta}(1,n)$ distribution.

Comment: @StubbornAtom so the exponent of second term i.e. (y-1) should be 2?

Comment: Why would there be a 2 or a 3? There is no need for guesswork. Derive the cdf and hence the pdf.

Comment: @StubbornAtom is cdf of uniform distribution for above (x-0)/(1-0) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Comment.** @StubbornAtom's link, more specifically [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Order_statistics_sampled_from_a_uniform_distribution) on order statistics of a sample from a uniform distribution,
gives the result $\mathsf{Beta}(1,n)$ along with an indication of the proof. [Perhaps also see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Related_distributions) on distributions related to beta distributions, about a dozen bullets down.]

A simulation in R for a million samples of size $n = 5$
approximates the distribution of the minimum observations in a such a sample.

```
 set.seed(527)
 min = replicate(10^6, min(runif(5))) 
 mean(min)
 [1] 0.1668423  # aprx E(min) = 1/6
```

Roughly and intuitively, "on average" the five observations (in order) will tend to lie at equal intervals: at points $1/6, 2/6, \dots, 5/ 6),$ so the smallest
will tend to be near $1/6.$

Here is a histogram of the simulated distribution of the minimum along with the density function of the distribution of the minimum.

[image]